# How to delete one data line from a structure array ? (with index)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, struct

I am trying to make a function, which deletes one line from a structure array, I give function the index of line I want to delete and the structure array. E.g. we have structure array :

```
Structure
{
string First;
string Second;
string Third;
string Fourth;
string Fifth;
}
```

Structure array :

```
Structure A[100];
int n;
```

So there are five string type elements in this structure array :

```
A[i].First A[i].Second A[i].Fourth A[i].Fifth // i is the index
```

Our function is like this :

```
void Delete(Structure A[], int index, int & n) 
{

Structure t;

for (int i = index; i < n-1; i++)
{
    t = A[i];
    A[i] = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = t;
    n--;
} 
}
```

So I give function index and I want the function to delete all elements of my structure array with that index ( so how can I take like the whole "line" of those elements, instead of deleting them one by one ?)

```
A[index].First A[index].Second A[index].Third A[index].Fourth A[index].Fifth
```

The function however doesn't work. Can you give me some tips/advises/suggestions, please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably want to do the `n--;` after the loop... general answer: use a `vector`

Comment: What is n, the number of elements starting at index `index` to remove?  Why is it by ref?

Comment: n declares how many lines of elements there are in my structure.. Let's think in this case that n = 5.

Comment: are the member of Structure of type std::string, or are they c-style strings (char array/char pointer)?

Comment: more specifically, are they [trivially copyable](en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable)?

Comment: These are std::string type

Comment: @jfevold1 Is it correct to use Structure t as if it contans a line of elements who have the same index ? I mean that for example : `Structure t = A[i]` so in my case `t = A[i].First and so on including A[i].Fifth as the last one` Can I use it like that ? Does A[i] contain like a line of elements of my structure with the same index ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Without the move operation in (c++11?), you can't improve on the answer from Serge (for non-trivially copyable types, like your std::string).  Side Note: I get the feeling (as I often do when people ask for help on academic assignments) that you're struggling to understand the assignment, which is absolutely necessary before solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first level, your question is basically: how to remove a line from an array whose used size is stored in an external variable (passed here as `n`)

The signature of your function is correct, the implementation is not. It should be:

```
void Delete(Structure A[], int index, int & n) 
{

    // eventually control index >= 0 and index < n...

    n -= 1;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = A[i + 1];
    }
}
```

If you have a recent version of C++ that support move semantics, you could speed up the operation by moving the strings instead of copying them:

```
    n -= 1;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = std::move(A[i + 1]);
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't look like my function is working, even after changing the loop. Any ideas what else could be wrong ?

Comment: `--n` will run before every iteration. It should be outside of the loop.

Comment: @Fozi absolutely right.  It's also against best practices (in my opinion) to put any side-affects in the `for()` statement (except the one explicitly stated in the third position, the whole point of the loop itself).

Comment: @Fozi: Oups... I should I read my own code :-(. Thanks for noticing